# How to align div on the same line Qweb report . Odoo 14

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo

I want to align 2 div in the same line , I used class row and col-lg- , but still not working .
What's wrong ?
Thanks

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="align-items-center">
       <div class="col-lg-6">1er element</div>
       <div class="col-lg-6">2nd element</div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try the following:

```xml
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="align-items-center">
       <div class="col-md-6">1er element</div>
       <div class="col-md-6">2nd element</div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

don't hesitate to let us know if it's working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same classes used in sale order report:

```
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-auto col-6">1er element</div>
    <div class="col-auto col-6">2nd element</div>
</div>
```